# How To List Posts From Newest To Oldest In ASP.NET MVC5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

I have a web app where users can posts items on the home page. Currently, the items on the home page are listed from oldest date to newest. This is not good because the users want to see the most recent posts when they visit the home page.

I have a DatePosted property in my post model that I use to track the time and date of a posting. How can I sort by Newest to Oldest using that property?

**Here is my Action that takes users to the home page where they can see posts:**

```
// GET: Posts
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var posts = db.Posts.ToList();

    return View(posts);
}
```

**The View:**

```
@model IEnumerable<DothanTrader.Models.Post>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}



@{
    int i = 5;
}
<div class="row">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        if (i == 5)
        {
            @:</div><div class="row">

            i = 1;
        }
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    @Html.ActionLink(@item.Title, "Details", "Post", new { id = item.PostId }, null) 
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body" style="min-height: 200px; max-height: 200px; ">
                    <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(item.Image))" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
                </div>
                <div class="panel-footer">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"> @item.Views</span> | <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-usd"> @item.Price</span>
                    <div class="pull-right">
                        <span>@item.DatePosted.Value.ToShortDateString()</span> 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        { i++; }
    }
</div>
```

**The Model (just in case you need it):**

```
public class Post
    {
        public int PostId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DatePosted { get; set; }
        public string Image { get; set; }
        public float Price { get; set; }
        public int  Views { get; set; }
        public int Likes { get; set; }
        public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
        public string ApplicationUserId { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `db.Posts.OrderByDescending(p => p.DatePosted).ToList()`

Comment: nice. Worked perfectly.

Comment: @Michael Please mark this as answer if it resolved your issue. Thanks

Comment: I will. It keeps telling me to wait five minutes when I try to accept the answer.

Comment: @Jonathan thanks for the reminder. I had accepted it earlier using the app on my phone but I guess it didn't like it.